# Take a file name as input and check if it exists

Tags: bash, shell

How do I create a Bash script that takes a file name as input? Then, if that file exists, it should print "File exists"; if not, print "File does not exist".

For example, if I ran `./do-i-exist.sh ./do-i-exist.sh`, the output should be only 'File exists'

```
file="$1"
read answer
if [ $file != -$2 ]
then
echo "File exists"
else
echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

This is what I'm working with but is not working for me, whenever I add an extension like .sh, .txt or something similar it won't find the file.

Comment: Can you explain what you think `if [ $file != -$2 ]` does?

Comment: What about `if [ -e "$1" ]; then echo "File exists"; else echo "File does not exist"; fi`

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm trying to use a boolean if the file exists then it should execute "File exists"

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thanks, from the looks of it, it may work but I need to put it down on a file. sh not just run it from the terminal

Comment: The code already is supposed to be run from a script.

Comment: is not working for me, as I said, it should take an input from a file and it should return an exist or doesn't exist response. Had been trying this for 3 days now with no luck

Comment: You have `file="$1"` and `read answer`. What do you think these lines do?

Comment: file is just a variable for $1 and read should be the command for the input.@jhnc

Comment: In a script (not when run from a shell prompt), `"$1"` refers to the first argument passed to the script. `read` takes input from stdin (ie. from your terminal unless the script input is redirected). `answer` is the variable `read` uses to store that input. However you aren't using it anywhere. And from a shell prompt, `file="$1"` will probably result in `"$file"` being the empty string.

Comment: exactly, you are right in everything, the problem here Is that I don't have control over the input since is a redirect. this is all have to work with ```Our files are having an existential crisis. Can you help us determine if they really exist? Create a Bash script that takes a file name as input. If that file exists, print File exists and if not, print File does not exist. Upload your script to the VM #4 home folder and run /challenge/do-i-exist with your script's location as the first argument to get the flag.``` @jhnc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank anyone and everyone who tried to help. After 3 hard working days, I found the answer, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$@"
if [ -f $file ]
then 
echo "File exists"
else
echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Using this table:

| Variable Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `$0` | The name of the Bash script |
| `$1` - `$9` | The first 9 arguments to the Bash script |
| `$#` | Number of arguments passed to the Bash script |
| `$@` | All arguments passed to the Bash script |
| `$?` | The exit status of the most recently run process |
| `$$` | The process ID of the current script |
| `$USER` | The username of the user running the script |
| `$HOSTNAME` | The hostname of the machine |
| `$RANDOM` | A random number |
| `$LINENO` | The current line number in the script |

I and other users were focused on using `$1` from my understanding this refers to the first argument passed to the script but for some reason, it wasn't working since it needed to pass more inputs.

As from my previous comments I didn't have control over the input. The input was hidden in a locked file, and I needed to feed my script to it.

From what we know `$0` is only used to check for the file names, `$1` to get the first statement and `$@` will just take anything(I guess).

I know absolutely nothing about bash and it was the first time ever using it, which is why it took me 3 days to solve this puzzle. This was part of a **CTF** and just like me, many others may struggle in the future to understand or know how to make a script that will just adapt to a series of inputs from a second script.

This is how it was supported to work:

I was given access to a very restricted server and on this server, I was given the `encrypted-file.sh` file. This file was supposed to be fed to `/path/to/myfile.sh` then `encrypted-file.sh` would execute a second command to open a third locked file hiding a flag on it.

This only works with the right bash file using the right variables on it for `encrypted-file.sh` to run without errors, which is what I accomplished here.

Comment: Good job digging in to the problem, but I must warn you that the answer doesn't hold water. `-f` can only check a single file name. You can't pass it all of the arguments in `$@` at once. Changing `$1` to `$@` is not going to fix whatever problem you've been having.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnKugelman actually it did, using the code I pasted here and using `$@` instead of `$1` the CTF was solved.

Comment: It sounds like you got past it somehow, but I think you only got it to accept your script by accident. I want to encourage you to keep probing and really try to understand what's going on. It's only truly solved if you understand what you did and why it worked.

Comment: `$@` is the list of all arguments passed to your script. You would use it if you were expecting multiple file names rather than just one file name. Issue 1: The problem spec doesn't mention multiple file names so I don't see why you'd use `$@`. Issue 2: `-f` can only check one file name at a time, so even if you did want to handle multiple file names, you can't pass all of them at once to a single `-f` test.

Comment: When I say "keep probing", play with your script, see what happens if you pass it the names of 2 files that exist; or 1 file that exists and 1 that doesn't; or 1 that doesn't and 1 that does; and so on. And before you actually run the script, predict in your head what you think will happen. Then run it and see if you were right. Always make predictions before you run tests -- don't just blindly test and observe.

Comment: *You would  use `$@` if you were expecting multiple file names rather than just one file name* Exactly! as I said here, this file that I needed to make was going to be used to feed a second file. Apparently, that second file executed multiple file names which explains why '$1' was not working for me. I didn't mention anything about multiple file names because everything was hidden, I just understand the whole workflow now that I solved the CTF. The whole time I thought it was a single file name from the input.

Answer (score 0):

The test if a file exists can be done like this

```
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
```

This tests for a regular file, not for other kinds of files like a directory.

Comment: yes, this is the right track but before the if statement, there should be an input, this is where I'm struggling to chain the whole code, the input should be the file name

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. Pass the name of the file while like `./do-i-exist.sh file_path`.

```bash
if [ -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "File Exists"
else
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Thank this look pretty neat, but can you add the input part? that's the part I'm missing, I need to use a file name as the input and from the input the script should say if the file exist or not in the dir

Comment: Quoting `"$1"` will fix the empty file name problem.

Comment: @JohnKugelman let's say we have ´./file.sh´ and `./do-i-exist.sh` if I run file.sh against any other file, it should tell me if the file is in the system. kind of like `Find /* randomfile.sh` which is why I need the script to take an `input` in this case the file name alone with the extension ex; sh, txt, php

Answer (score 0):

I used a while loop because it made sense in my case because I really needed a file for the script to work.

```
restore_file="$1"
while [ ! -f "$restore_file" ]
do
  echo "File not found: $restore_file"
  echo "Please provide a valid file:"
  read restore_file
done
```

As written above, `$1` is the first argument given to the script. In this case if no argument is given or that is not a file, it will prompt again.

By the way, use `-d` instead of `-f` to check for a directory.